# Convert text Date to DateTime?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime-format

In the `Sent` field (`varchar`) the text are formatted like this:

Tue Dec 04 16:10:05 GMT 2012

I would like to convert into `DATETIME` field type, what is the solution to that in SQL query?

Comment: Is this a specific format?

Comment: Yes all the rows are like that.

Comment: Do you know how the data is formatted? Some specific ISO format, etc on sender side?

Comment: I don't, data was imported from CSV file.

Comment: `DATETIME` cannot convey as much information as that current field; in particular, timezone information will be lost.  `TIMESTAMP` would at least convert everything to UTC, but beware if it is important to retain the timezone information associated with the original data.

Comment: I don't mind just convert to `DATE` format without time included.

Comment: Are all your timestamps in GMT format or do you have other timzones as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, one uses [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) for tasks of this sort.

However, the presence of timezone information in this case presents a problem as `STR_TO_DATE()` cannot parse such strings.  I suggest first using [`SUBSTRING_INDEX()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) together with [`CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) to extract the data excluding the timezone:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(
         CONCAT(
           SUBSTRING_INDEX(Sent, ' ',  4),
           ' ',
           SUBSTRING_INDEX(Sent, ' ', -1)
         ),
         '%a %b %d %T %Y'
       )
FROM   my_table
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bf76b/1/0).

To convert the data type of the existing column:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
  ADD COLUMN Sent_TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP AFTER Sent
;

UPDATE my_table
SET    Sent_TIMESTAMP = STR_TO_DATE(
         CONCAT(
           SUBSTRING_INDEX(Sent, ' ',  4),
           ' ',
           SUBSTRING_INDEX(Sent, ' ', -1)
         ),
         '%a %b %d %T %Y'
       )
;

ALTER TABLE my_table
  DROP   Sent,
  CHANGE Sent_TIMESTAMP Sent TIMESTAMP
;
```

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back: That's just a property of how sqlfiddle formats date types as strings for presentation; it isn't how MySQL treats the data internally.

Comment: @eggyal , your solution assumes the timezone is not needed. If the data actually uses different timezones your fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bf76b/1/0 does not deal with differing timezones.

Comment: @meewoK: Per [the OP's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16444501/convert-text-date-to-datetime/16444742?noredirect=1#comment23586416_16444501).

Comment: @eggyal: It's very easy to introduce bugs like that. A datetime such as Nov 1 23:15... is it Nov 1 or Nov 2? Depends on timezone information which may be important (may also not be).

Answer (score 1):

### The simplest way to do it would be the following (given all dates are GMT):

```
SELECT str_to_date( substring_index(DateString, " ", -5) , 
       "%M %d %H:%i:%S GMT %YYYY" )
FROM DateStrings;
```

I trim out the 3 character day of the week (it is redundant) and than use str_to_date to parse your specific format.

### Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/92a67/21

Comment: Why trim the day of week when `STR_TO_DATE()` can parse it with `%a`?  How would you handle the timezone?  Also, `%M` expects the month name in full, not as a 3-letter abbreviation.

Comment: Actually, %M works with the short versions of months as well. I've updated my answer and it seems to work perfectly. Also, you don't need to trim out GMT as can be seen in my fiddle. Only remaining issue is the timezone :)

Comment: Er, your fiddle shows the year as `0001`: delighted to hear ideas on how one can resolve that without stripping GMT from the string.

Comment: @eggyal Actually, +0000 means the timezone is 0000.. you will notice my friend the year is correctly parsed as 2012 and 2013 in each row. If the User has all data as GMT (+000) the code works flawlessly for those conditions :) You will notice at http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/92a67/3 that year is extracted correctly.

Comment: My comment referred to [your previous fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c306f/8), before your latest update.  In this latest update, you require that all date strings contain the literal timestamp `GMT` which may or may not suit the OP's needs.

Comment: I'm assuming it is GMT. As the timezone is included in the example. The OP has not replied as to if the data includes this or not. Based on what has been given this covers the requirements.